# Cant compile solidity files using correct Solc version

Tags: node.js, npm, blockchain, solidity

when I try to run my contracts by using:

> truffle migrate --network infura

I get thrown an error saying all my files require a higher pragma solidity version, in the error it says I'm currently using solc 0.5.16 yet I've ran

> npm uninstall

and then

> install

and when I run

> NPM list or solcjs --version

it shows solc@0.8.4, could anyone help me identify the issue thanks.

Comment: What is the compatibility definition in your `.sol` files? The `pragma solidity ...` - is it `0.5.16`, `^0.5.16` or any other value? Also what is the exact error message? This will help other users to troubleshoot your issue more easily.

Comment: @PetrHejda all my pragma statements have a ^ before the version number, I thought that was so any version that it states and higher can run it ...

And yes that's why I'm asking as i cant find any good documentation out there to help......

error-

.sol:1:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;

Comment: It seems that you have two copies of `solcjs` - one v0.5.16 (dependency of truffle) and one v0.8.4 (separately installed package). Can you verify whether `truffle version` prints the `0.5.16` or `0.8.4` version? My guess is the first one.

Comment: @PetrHejda it shows v5.3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason visual code choose a different solc compiler than the one i installed so when you run a solidity you have to use

> solcjs --bin --base-path . ./file name

and that will use the solc that you installed using

> npm install -g solc

Worked for me, hope it works for all of you